# how to start/stop all tasks in Spring Cloud DataFlow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Does Spring Cloud Data Flow support start/stop all tasks features? (start /stop at the same time) and how to do that?
Can I do that by updating from database?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

You can stop a task execution by invoking a stop on a specific task execution ID. You can refer more to this in the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stopping-task-execution).

If you are running a Spring Batch application (which is a task app itself), then it can be restarted after being stopped.